# Unhandled Exception when project built

Tags: c#, build, unhandled-exception, rebuild

I am getting `Unhandled Exception` error randomly in my project while taking fingerprints. Sometimes when I clean and rebuild my project problem being solved. But when I rebuild again problem appear. How can I handle this problem? 
Here is the error show in Windows EventViewer

> Faulting application name: GetFingerprints.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x543daf42
>   Faulting module name: GreenBit.dll, version: 1.5.0.0, time stamp: 0x543b738b
>   Exception code: 0xc0000005
>       Fault offset: 0x0001e984
>       Faulting process id: 0x%9
>       Faulting application start time: 0x%10
>       Faulting application path: %11
>       Faulting module path: %12
>       Report Id: %13

Comment: is it occurring when the project is compiling, or during runtime?

Comment: occouring during runtime.

Comment: from my googling, the exception code can refer to pretty much anything from compatibility issues, permissions issues (try running as administrator), faulty RAM, rtc. Have you been able to replicate the error on other computers?

Comment: try following the steps outlined here: http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2007/05/29/basic-debugging-of-an-application-crash.aspx

Comment: Yes, this error replicate on other computers too. But on some of them occouring rarely, some of them often.

Comment: is it always in the same place, or randomly?

Comment: just randomly i cannot detect where or when.

Comment: I'm going to assume you have your own logging in the application and that isn't indicating a cause. So I guess you're going to have to figure it out the hard way, using the DrWatson application Microsoft provides and analyse the fallover. Follow the steps here which I provided earlier : http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2007/05/29/basic-debugging-of-an-application-crash.aspx